# Why i get Error 500 fetching data with axios

Tags: javascript, async-await, xmlhttprequest, axios, httprequest

I am doing little project to learn and put it in my project section
I get problem like this:

> GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?q=rice 500 (Internal Server Error)
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
>       at createError (createError.js:16)
>       at settle (settle.js:17)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)

I tried with using axios headers (i found this sugestion on another forum but it dosn't work)
My code for fetching data looks like this

```
 export async function fetchData(text) {
    const proxy = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`;
    const base = `http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/`;
    const baseEnd = `q=${text}`;
    const data = await axios
      .get(`${proxy}${base}?${baseEnd}`)
      .then(data =>console.log(data));
    const recipes = data.data.results;
    return recipes.length > 0 ? recipes : false;
  }
```

function called here:

```
async function getRecipes(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  const text = e.target[1].value; 
  const loader = '<div class="loader"></div>'; 
  container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', loader); 
  const recipes = await fetchData(text); 
  document.querySelector('.loader').remove(); 
  displayRecipes(recipes); 
}
```

Comment: If you still have that error, add full code of that function and at least part of the code where you calling it.

Comment: this is the code where i call a fetch 
`export async function fetchData(text) {
    const proxy = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`;
    const base = `http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?`;
    const baseEnd = `q=${text}`;
    const data = await axios.get(`${proxy}${base}?${baseEnd}`).catch(err => console.log(err));
    console.log(data)
    return recipes.length > 0 ? recipes : false;
}`
and this is where i call the function 
`

Comment: and this is where i call my function
`async function getRecipes(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const text = e.target[1].value;
    const loader = '<div class="loader"></div>';
    container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', loader);
    const recipes = await fetchData(text);
    document.querySelector('.loader').remove();
    displayRecipes(recipes);
}`

Comment: This was working 2 days ago and yesterday I wanted to code my little app and it isn't even fetching data

Comment: So error point you to at least 3 scripts. May be you calling getRecepies() from another async function and it also wrapped in Promise? I just few days ago fight against authorization flow in Vuejs and had same error. So to localize it I moved all my logic in "root" function and then one by one started move parts of the code to relative "child" functions. And problem was missing .catch() on some level.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch possible error from Promise (as axios.get() return Promise type object).

```
axios.get(`${proxy}${base}?${baseEnd}`)
  .then(data =>console.log(data))
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Comment: try {await axios.get(`${proxy}${base}?${baseEnd}`)} catch(err){console.log(err)} -- Any idea why this is not being handled using await.